# Pentaho Spoon.bat doesn't start

Tags: pentaho

I downloaded the latest version of pentaho data integration (pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342), I set the variable system (of jdk) but when I tried to start Spoon.bat it didn't start , I downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.zip and copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar file in the data-integration/lib folder but nothing have changed

```
C:\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342 (2)\data-integration>Spoon.bat
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe

C:\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342 (2)\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program 
Files\Java\
jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" 
"-Dh
ttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "- 
DKETT
LE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "- 
DKETTLE
_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar 
launche
r\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32

C:\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342 (2)\data-integration>echo %PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
```

So how can solve this problem ?

Comment: Windows system/environment variables do not become 'available' on the go, set the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME to whatever the directory is and restart your system, try again. There is also a 'set-pentaho-env.bat' file in your data-integration, that will try and find the location of your JDK/JRE javaw.exe and set the variable.

Comment: Well, I found PDIPortable.exe much simpler and I used it, thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I was able to run it just changing this flag: `"-Xmx2048m"` to a lower amount.

Edit Spoon.bat to change: `PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`